# how to fix de-structure forEach callback parameter to return an object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

am trying to loop through an array of user objects to return a user object if a match is found by destructuring the the forEach callback parameter

i have tried running the loop like this

```
let users = [];

users.push({   age: 40,   weight: 75,   height: 6,   country: 'Nigeria',   name: 'Charles Odili',   id: 'dfhb454768DghtF' });
         users.push({  age: 20,  weight: 89,  height: 8,  country: 'Nigeria',  name: 'Emeka Mamah',  id: 'dfhb454768Dg' });

let userId = "dfhb454768Dg";

 let user = users.find((user, { id } = user) => {    return { id, name, weight, height, country} = (user.id === userId);

});

console.log(user);
```

i expect a user object of the matching id which comes out fine when i log to the console. but when i evaluate the method it just doesn't work

Comment: Your code works for me just fine http://plnkr.co/edit/6eUhKJwt9JPWxCsp80II?p=preview

Comment: the code you posted doesn't use `forEach` ... did you post the wrong code? Did you ask the wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must confess I don't understand what your `find` expression is doing, or why it should work.

What I can tell you is the shorter and more idiomatic way to write the same thing: `let user = users.find(({ id }) => id === userId);`

If I substitute that into your code I get this:

```
let users = [];

users.push({ age: 40, weight: 75, height: 6, country: 'Nigeria', name: 'Charles Odili', id: 'dfhb454768DghtF' });

users.push({ age: 20, weight: 89, height: 8, country: 'Nigeria', name: 'Emeka Mamah', id: 'dfhb454768Dg' });

let userId = "dfhb454768Dg";

let user = users.find(({ id }) => id === userId);

console.log(user);
```

And that seems to work (too).

Comment: thanks so much. you saved the day